# Call a public method of a object's actual type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Consider following code

```
using System.Reflection;
public class Sample { 
    private class User { 
        public string Name; 
    } 
    private List<User> Users = new List<User> { 
        new User() { Name = "Alice" }, 
        new User() { Name = "Bob" } 
    }; 
}
var sample = new Sample();
var usersOfSample = typeof(Sample).GetField("Users", BindingFlags.Instance | 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(sample);
```

With reflection, I can get the value of Users, while it is a List of a **private** class. Now I want to call List.Clear() on users.
My first idea is convert it into dynamic. However, following code does not work as my expectation.

```
dynamic usersOfSampleDyn = (usersOfSample as dynamic);
usersOfSampleDyn.Clear();
```

It throws a RuntimeBinderException.

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Clear'
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
at MyCode
```

Later I try this code in C# Interactive, it says

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Clear'
+ System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1<T0, TRet>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, T0)
```

Using reflection to call this method works, as following

```
usersOfSample.GetType().GetMethod("Clear").Invoke(usersOfSample, new object[0]);
```

Here is my question:
1. Why I can't call Clear() when cast usersOfSample into dynamic?
1.1 During runtime, is usersOfSampleDyn resolved as a `List<T>` or a `object { List<T> }`?
1.2  If usersOfSampleDyn was resolved as a `object { List<T> }`, how to convert it into `List<T>` or anything I can call `Clear()` on?
Note: `T` is private.
2. What's the correct way to call a public List method on `object { List<InaccessibleClass> }`?

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean by `dynamic { List<T> }` or even `dynamic { object { List<T> } }`. `usersOfSampleDyn` is of course `dynamic`, with its type at runtime being resolved as `object`. However it´ll be nice if you could provide the exact error-messages you recieve.

Comment: If you know that you are working with a `List<T>` you can just cast to the non generic `IList` and work with that.

Comment: @thehennyy I think OPs problem is that `T` is *private* within the `Sample`-class. Which makers me wonder *why* it is private if OP needs it outside the `Sample`-class also.

Comment: @thehennyy Casting to `IList` does the trick.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yeah true, thats probably the underlying problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere More details added. I'm trying to make a game plugin, but I didn't find how to change my hook's priority. The plugin is going to forward all data to another TcpConnection, and this hook should be invoked before anything else. So I'm trying to clear that hook and rewrite the default action, but it use internal struct to store the list of registered hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why I can't call Clear() when cast usersOfSample into dynamic?

because

> 1.1 During runtime, is usersOfSampleDyn resolved as a List<T> or a object { List<T> }?

it's `object {List<T>}`.

Edit:

> The reason dynamic treats the object as object is that dynamic will be treated as the most derived type that is accessible to where it is called.

as mentioned in [Jon Hanna's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532079/call-a-public-method-of-a-objects-actual-type/51537162#comment90042223_51537162).

> 1.2 If usersOfSampleDyn was resolved as a object { List<T> }, how to convert it into List or anything I can call Clear() on?

`List<T>` implements the non-generic `IList`, simply cast to it:

```
((IList)usersOfSample).Clear();
```

> 2. What's the correct way to call a public List method on object { List<InaccessibleClass> }?

You don't. If the class in inaccessible it was done that way for a reason. Change the object visibility if it is your own code, otherwise don't muck around in internal state of external code, it can break at any point and have unintended and hard to debug side effects.

But if you really need to it's reflection or casting to IList.

Comment: I'd add that the reason `dynamic` treats the object as `object` is that `dynamic` will be treated as the most derived type that is accessible to where it is called. If it was `List<T>` and the `T` was a type accessible to where it was called then going through `dynamic` would have worked, but if `T` isn't accessible the the most derived type allowable is `object`. There are ways of convincing the binder used by `dynamic` to do otherwise, but they're convoluted and brittle and the answer here shows they're also unnecessary. Another way would have been to access the `Clear` through reflection.